# Elliptical gradient rotation in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, gradient

I implemented basic elliptical gradient in GLSL and it is working fine. However I failed rotating the gradient. My code is below:
vertex shader

```
uniform mat4 camera;
uniform mat4 model;

in vec3 vert; // coordinates of vertex
in vec2 vertTexCoord; //pseudo texture coordinates, used for calculating relative fragment position

out vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main() {
    fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord; //pass to fragment shader
    gl_Position = camera * model * vec4(vert, 1); //apply transformations
}
```

fragment shader

```
uniform vec2 gradientCenter; //center of gradient
uniform vec2 gradientDimensions; //how far gradient goes in right and up direction respectively
uniform vec2 gradientDirection; //rotation of gradient, not used..yet

in vec2 fragTexCoord;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
    vec2 gradient = gradientCenter - fragTexCoord; //gradient itself
    gradient.x = gradient.x * (1.0 / gradientDimensions.x); //relative scale on right direction, currently X axis
    gradient.y = gradient.y * (1.0 / gradientDimensions.y); //relative scale on up direction, currently Y axis
    float distanceFromLight = length(gradient); //lenght determines output color
    finalColor = mix(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), distanceFromLight * 2); //mixing red and blue, placeholder colors
}
```

to better illustrate, in the upper picture is what I have and is working, in the lower picture what is my goal. How to improve my code to allow elliptical gradient manipulation as shown on lower picture?
[image: illustration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `gradientDirection` is the normalized direction of the first principal axis. Then you can calculate the coordinates in the local system with the dot product:

```
vec2 secondaryPrincipal = vec2(gradientDirection.y, -gradientDirection.x);
vec2 gradient = gradientCenter - fragTexCoord; //gradient itself
vec2 localGradient(dot(gradient, gradientDirection)  * (1.0 / gradientDimensions.x),
                   dot(gradient, secondaryPrincipal) * (1.0 / gradientDimensions.y));
float distanceFromLight = length(localGradient); 
//...
```

Comment: Funny, I was *so* close... I only multiplied it with gradient once more.